# Add QSqlQueryModel or index value to QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is there a way to add my `QSqlQueryModel` to a `QListWidget`? If not is there a way to add the database row id to a `QListWidgetItem`?

I cant figure this out from the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html) on `QListWidget`.  I can add items to the list but can only think to use the row number of the item as the hidden index which wont work if index numbers are out of order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is the deal:

The `QListWidget` is part of the older Qt3 data widget set.

The widget you actually want is part of the newer "interview" Qt MVC framework.  It is called `QListView`.

It can be a bit confusing.

In general: A "*QxxxxView*" widget can be bound to a "*QxxxxModel*" object, such as the `QSqlQueryModel` you asked about.

See:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistview.html

And:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html

Lot's of good examples. For instance:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-querymodel.html

Good luck.
:)